# Firebase not processing analytics if the Firebase key is not present at build time

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

I only use Firebase for Crashlytics. The Android app needs to read the Firebase Key from a property that is not available at build time, so instead of using the default json configuration file it uses the following code which is executed during `Application`'s `onCreate()` :

```
val builder = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setProjectId(firebaseProjectId)
            .setApplicationId(applicationId)
            .setApiKey(firebaseKey)
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, builder.build())
```

This change was made some months ago and I've noticed that the **firebase analytics** stopped worked since the change was published. I do receive crash reports from crashlytics but all of the other data that is grabbed automatically is not there anymore: active users, unique users, analytics events, etc.

So Crashlytics is giving very bad data because it can only take as unique users the ones that still have older versions of the app.

Am I missing additional setups for Firebase Analytics to work under these scheme?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have gotten rid of the google-services.json file that [you would use to integrate with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file). Your Firebase Analytics integration won't work without that file. You can download it again from your Firebase project and add it to the app project again.

Comment: Yes i got rid of the file, because the key needs to change after it is build, but I'll review if it can be edited from the apk afterwards.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't read your question thoroughly enough.  I see now that you're setting the Google App ID with setApplicationId().  A couple of things to check would be that the applicationId you're setting is correct, and that FirebaseApp.initializeApp is actually getting called.